# How to convert ImageUri to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to compress my image because imageview is not accepting high resolution images. so for compressing image i need to convert my imageuri to bitmap[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZDU0.png)

Comment: Check this out [convert uri to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729200/how-to-convert-uri-to-bitmap/48729608).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Bitmap from an Uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879992/how-to-get-bitmap-from-an-uri)